# Restricting no. of columns in a row ng-repeat : angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page to display my friends list for our web application. My problem is that I cant restrict the number of friends shown in one row. I have to display 3 friends in each row:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left:200px;">   
        <div ng-repeat="favourite in  favouriteData.data.result">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                <div class="fav_image" >
                    <img ng-src='/assets/images/profilePics/{{favourite.username +"/"+favourite.profilePic}}' style="height:100px;width:100px;"/>
                    <h4 class="aju_fav">{{favourite.username}}</h4>
                    <h4 class="aju_fav">{{favourite.city}}</h4>
                    <h4 class="aju_fav"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none;" ng-click="makeUnfavourite(favourite.userId,$index);remove(favouriteData.data.result,$index)">Un-Favourite</a></h4>
                    <div class=" pull-left user_btm_right"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
    </div>
```

plz help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *always* display 3 columns per row (independently from the screen width) you can simply use `col-xs-4` (enclosing in a `<div class="row">` containing `ng-repeat`):

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="favourite in  favouriteData.data.result" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="fav_image">
        <img ng-src='http://192.168.1.75/zentiera/assets/images/profilePics/{{favourite.username +"/"+favourite.profilePic}}' style="height:100px;width:100px;"/>
        <h4 class="aju_fav">{{favourite.username}}</h4>
        <h4 class="aju_fav">{{favourite.city}}</h4>
        <h4 class="aju_fav"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none;" ng-click="makeUnfavourite(favourite.userId,$index);remove(favouriteData.data.result,$index)">Un-Favourite</a></h4>
        <div class=" pull-left user_btm_right"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this answer display one friend in each row.

Comment: working on it on a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/, not working yet... :-(

Comment: I think <div class="row"> should be in out of ng-repeat .

Comment: Yes, thanks, corrected. Yet not displaying 3 columns in fiddle... :-(

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use 'limitTo' filter component in ng. Here is [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo.)

```
<div ng-repeat="favourite in  favouriteData.data.result | limitTo:3">
```

Comment: Don't answer twice on the same question

Comment: `limitTo` filter restricts whole result set. It can't be used to limit no. of columns per row. As you can refer to angular docs...  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo